# receiving files from client on a python socket server

Tags: python, sockets, http

I'm creating a HTTP web server from scratch using python's built-in module socket and I want to upload files to that server, the problem is the Content-Type is multipart/from-data with a boundary but with a blank body only when uploading files either by a browser or a client library like requests, aiohttp. I had tried to read about multipart forms but I still don't understand how to get file details like name and content.
This is the code, what am I doing wrong ?

```py
import socket


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("localhost", 1234))
s.listen()
d = """<!DOCTYPE html>\n
    <html>\n
    <head>\n
    </head>\n
    <body>\n
    <form  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">\n
    <input type="file" name="file"/>\n
    <button type="submit">post</button>\n
    </form>\n
    </body>\n
    </html>"""

print("started !")
while True:
    con, adr = s.accept()
    print(con.recv(4096).decode())
    con.sendall(
        bytes(
            f"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nContent-Length: {len(d)}\r\n\n{d}",
            "utf-8",
        )
    )
    con.close()

s.close()
```

this is the request I see when receiving a file

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1234
User-Agent: python-requests/2.25.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 144
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=8ec9d4156e1a843a34fc2a8fd4221cf0
```

Comment: The headers of the response look correct. How do you try to read the response and why do you say that the body is empty? You do not show the part where you try to process the response...

Comment: that's all what print(con.recv(4096).decode()) shows, just the headers without the body

Comment: You are assuming that the full request can be read within a single `recv`. This assumption is wrong. You need to repeatedly call `recv` until you have the full request. To determine when the request is fully received you need to properly understand the HTTP protocol. See the HTTP standard for this, which defines the necessary semantics.

Comment: Why I posted this in your opinion because I don't know and I don't understand how to do it properly, maybe a brief explanation or example code will help